# Interview question: What are the chances of the user being Genuine?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, machine-learning

This is an actual interview question.:

A website has a system called The "findoo" that blocks brokers from using the website. It is empirically observed that the chances of a user of website is a broker is 1/100. Let's say "findoo" identifies a particular user to be Broker. "findoo" is a ML based engine that has an error rate. "findoo" identifies 1 out of 1000 users wrongly as broker when he is not a broker. "findoo" identifies broker as broker 999 out of 1000 times. Now Given "findoo" has stated the user is a broker, what are the chances of the user being Genuine?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is like the classic "diagnosed with rare disease" problem. In this case, the "rare disease" is being a broker.